# Elasticsearch query to find a US street address in an analyzed string

Tags: elasticsearch

How would you create an efficient query to look for street addresses in a string? For example, a user's bio could say "We are located at 123 Main St" and the string "123 Main St" should be a match. The pattern I need is: one or more numbers (e.g. [0-9]+), followed by 1-4 words (but not 0, as explained below) that can be anything (the name of the street, e.g. "Main" or "South Fifth" or "Martin Luther King Jr"), and ending with a word like "Street" or "Avenue."

Here's a preliminary query that I've created that works but runs very slowly:

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "regexp": {
                      "details.bio": "[0-9]+"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "regexp": {
                      "details.bio": "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "regexp": {
                      "details.bio": "St|st|street|Street|ave|Ave|AVE|Avenue|avenue|blvd|BLVD|Blvd|boulevard|Boulevard|drive|Drive|dr|DR|Dr|lane|Lane|Ln|ln|Road|road|Rd|rd"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop": 0,
            "in_order": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The part of this query that is so expensive is the second regexp "[a-zA-Z0-9]+". The first alternative I tried was removing this and adding a "slop" of 4, but this has too many false positives when the slop is 0 (e.g. it matches a bio with "I am 21. Street smart..."). So I need to require a distance of 1-4 words, but not 0, between the first expression (the street number) and the second expression (St, Blvd, etc) without using a wildcard.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I made use of the "span_not" search. Include everything up to slop=4 and then exclude slop=0. Runs in about 2s vs 1m+.

```
{
    "span_not": {
        "include": {
            "span_near": {
                "clauses": [
                    {
                        "span_multi": {
                            "match": {
                                "regexp": {
                                    "details.bio": "[0-9]+"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "span_multi": {
                            "match": {
                                "regexp": {
                                    "details.bio": "St|st|street|Street|ave|Ave|AVE|Avenue|avenue|blvd|BLVD|Blvd|boulevard|Boulevard|drive|Drive|dr|DR|Dr|lane|Lane|Ln|ln|Road|road|Rd|rd"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "slop": 4,
                "in_order": true
            }
        },
        "exclude": {
            "span_near": {
                "clauses": [
                    {
                        "span_multi": {
                            "match": {
                                "regexp": {
                                    "details.bio": "[0-9]+"
                                }
                            }
                        }

                },
                {
                    "span_multi": {
                        "match": {
                            "regexp": {
                                "details.bio": "St|st|street|Street|ave|Ave|AVE|Avenue|avenue|blvd|BLVD|Blvd|boulevard|Boulevard|drive|Drive|dr|DR|Dr|lane|Lane|Ln|ln|Road|road|Rd|rd"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "slop": 0,
            "in_order": true
        }
    }
}
```

}